# OpenCV on Android: Efficient way to get a byte[] array from many mats

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat

I have a list of mats and I need to convert them into a byte[] array. The problem is the high overhead this produce. The arraycopy part works fine, so don't worry about that. My question is if exists a better way to do it than this:

```
  // These array comes allocated an filled with data
  byte[] patches; // Big array to store all patches
  int offsets[];  // Array with positions to copy

  for(int i = 0; i < matList.size(); i++) 
  {
        // Create a little array of mat size and get the data
        int size = matList.get(i).rows() * matList.get(i).cols();
        byte[] patch = new byte[size];      
        matList.get(i).get(0, 0, patch);
        // Copy this little array to the big array
        System.arraycopy(patch, 0, patches, offsets[i], patch.length);
  }
```

If I'm not mistaken, in Java I can't pass a reference of big patch array with an offset to the *mat.get(0, 0, array)* function, to avoid the allocation of all these little patches.

Answer (score 0):

If all your `Mat`s have the same width, then you can try to join them to a single `Mat` object with [Core.vconcat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html) method. Then you will be able to get raw bytes with single `get`.

Comment: Unfortunately they are of different sizes. Nice tip anyway.